# Probability Problem; which distribution to use and how to find the "mean"?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've been working on my homework for a while, but I got stuck with this question:

---

A  trading  company  has  nine  computers  that  are  used  to  trade  on  the  New  York  Stock 
Exchange.  The  probability  of  a  computer  failing  in  a  day  is  0.04  and  the  computers  fail 
independently.  Computers  are  repaired  in  the  evening  and  each  day  is  an  independent 
trial.

(a) What  is  the  probability  that  seven  computers  fail  in  a  day?

(b) What  is  the  mean  number  of  days  until a  specific  computer  fails?

(c) What  is  the  mean  number  of  days  until  seven  computers  fail  in  the  same  day?

---

I don't understand, how can I tell which distribution to employ. From what I understand I can model (a) as a Binomial Distribution, but in (b) and (c); I don't really get it. What distribution to be used? What is meant by "Mean number of 'days'? and what is meant by 'specific'. And is there is a general method or advice on how to approach such problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

a) Here you indeed need a binomial distribution.

b) Note that the computer has 0.04 chance to fail every day. So the probability of the number of days till failure follows a geometric distribution.

c) Here you cannot use a common distribution, but you can use the independence of the seven computers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in (b) can it be said that $$ \mu = 1/p = 1/0.04 = 25  days $$ and for (c) Is it possible to model the intersection of 7 computers failing as one event and then approach it geometrically? like $$\mu = 1/p = 1/(1.64×10^{-10}) = 6103515625  days$$ ? The number is pretty big in (c), is it correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. In c) your probability of failure is $0.04^7$ since all computers are independent. The mean numbers of days is then 1 over this number.

Comment: Brilliant, thank a lot. Your answer was really helpful.